# How to extract folder name in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My folder name as movie title and after extracting movie name as folder in python then it will be use as a movie title to find out the movie discription by usnibg omdb API and then find out the rate of the movie when we seen the movie rate then the folder will be deleted

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to turn a path like `"/foo/bar/baz"` into just `"baz"`?

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please try to invest some time into writing complete sentences. As it is, this question is going to end up being deleted.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.walk(top, topdown=Ture, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
```

The walk() function in module os can traverse all files in a folder.

The function returns a tupple(dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

Parameters:

> dirpath：string, the path of directory,
>
> dirnames：list, includes all directories’ name
>
> filenames：list，includes all files’ name.

p.s.

dirnames and filenames didn’t include the path information, if you need entire path, use os.path.join(dirpath, dirnames)